# How to use xterm translations to use level3 shifted KP_Prior for scroll-back?

Tags: xterm

I am using LWIN key as level3 shift using level3(lwin_switch) symbol.
On this level I am using 'i' and 'm' as KP_Prior and KP_Next, so LWIN+i will scroll page up and LWIN+m will scroll page down in Pale Moon.

How to use the same key combination for scrolling in xterm? I have tried to use the translations feature but am not successful. I've used it before only for simple things like changing scrolling modifier from <kbd>Shift</kbd> -> <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>.

Answer (score 1):

Not an answer, but close enough for my purposes.
Now I can scroll in xterm by using the Meta (Alt_L) modifier in combination with level3 shifted Prior/Next keys in place of physical 'i' and 'm'.

```
XTerm*vt100.translations: #override \n\
Meta <KeyPress> Return:fullscreen(toggle) \n\
Shift <KeyPress> Prior:insert() \n\
Shift <KeyPress> Next:insert() \n\
Meta <KeyPress> Prior:scroll-back(1,halfpage) \n\
Meta <KeyPress> Next:scroll-forw(1,halfpage)
```

For completeness sake this is my modified keymap in case anybody is interested:

```
hidden partial modifier_keys
xkb_symbols "swapescape" {
key <TAB> { [ Escape ] };
key <ESC>  { [ Tab ] };
};

partial alphanumeric_keys
xkb_symbols "ee" {
include "us"
name[Group1] = "English (US keyboard with custom overlay on level3)";

// hjkl
key <AC06>  { [           h,  H,           Left                  ]  };
key <AC07>  { [           j,  J,           Down                  ]  };
key <AC08>  { [           k,  K,           Up                    ]  };
key <AC09>  { [           l,  L,           Right                 ]  };

key <AD08>  { [           i,  I,           Prior                 ]  };
key <AB07>  { [           m,  M,           Next                  ]  };

include "eurosign(e)"
};
```

Still, I'd like to know if it's possible to make it work without (Meta) modifier.